# Put a child element underneath its parent

Tags: css, navigation, position, z-index

I can't figure this out. I'm trying to have a menu-item be displayed over top of it's submenu. By default wordpress has this code.

```
<div class="nav--primary">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>
      <a>List Item</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>subitem</li>
      </ul></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using this CSS:

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: maroon;
  z-index: 1;
  top:45px;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitchell3417/ugcsx3oo/9/). I need the maroon to be below the orange. I've seen some example solutions online but I cannot get any of them to work with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eh1mwwsj/1/):

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: maroon;
  z-index: -1;
  top:45px;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. If I do that in my real problem (with my navigation) then the body of the page shows through the submenu. I suppose and could make the z-index on the body even lower.

Comment: Thanks. I think the next step would be to mark this answer as correct and create a new question with the code from your real problem.